# Python when checking if scraped element exists in list

Tags: python, indexing

I keep getting an error when I am using an if else statement in python. I want my script to check if an index exists and if it does then run the code, if not then run another code. I get the error `ValueError: 'Named Administrator' is not in list`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url_3 = 'https://www.brightscope.com/form-5500/basic-info/107299/Orthopedic-Institute-Of-Pennsylvania/15801790/Orthopedic-Institute-Of-Pennsylvania-401k-Profit-Sharing-Plan/'
page = requests.get(url_3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
divs = [e.get_text() for e in soup.findAll('span')]


if divs.index('Named Administrator'):
    index = divs.index('Named Administrator')
    contact = divs[index + 1]
else:
    contact = '-'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing `index`, do a `__contains__` test:

```
if 'Named Administrator' in divs:
```

and move forward only if `Named Administrator` actually exists in `divs` list, so you won't get the `ValueError`.

---

Another consideration is that membership test in lists has O(N) time complexity, so if you are doing this for a large list, probably use a set instead:

```
{e.get_text() for e in soup.findAll('span')}
```

but as sets are unordered you won't be able to use `index`-ing.

So either think about something else that would work on sets as well i.e. no need to get next value by indexing.

Or you can use a set for membership test, and list for getting the next value. The cost here might be higher or lower based on your actual context and you can only find out that by profiling:

```
divs_list = [e.get_text() for e in soup.findAll('span')]
divs_set = set(divs_list)

if 'Named Administrator' in divs_set:
    index = divs_list.index('Named Administrator')
    contact = divs_list[index + 1]
```

Comment: I don't think it need the complication of making it a set since those values are the only ones that would ever be present or not.

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish Great. Whatever suits you :)